# Connecting Hive Table from Pentaho Kettle

Tags: hive, pentaho, hiveql, kettle, cloudera-cdh

I'm trying to connect to push data from mysql to Hive table in cloudera via Kettle job i downloaded jdbc hive driver from cloudera site to the lib folder in kettle, but im getting this error

> Error connecting to database: (using class org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver)
>   Unable to load Hive JDBC driver for the currently active Hadoop configuration

Im using Cloudera 5.4 and the driver downloaded is Cloudera_HiveJDBC4_2.5.4.1006

Please Help.

Comment: Read about configuring your shim and make sure you have the bigdata plugin installed.

Comment: Thanks Codek, but i configured the shim and installed the plugin

Answer (score 0):

[Set up Pentaho to Connect to a Cloudera Cluster](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.1/0H0/070/030/010)

Set your `plugin.properties` like following:

`active.hadoop.configuation=cdh54`

Please be careful, there are multiple `plugin.properties` up to environment.